# ssis data conversion in derived column

Tags: ssis

I posted one proble yesterday related to data conversion.
Now i am rephraising the problem as below.

I have one Text fle where i have date and Time as string.
So i need to read that strin (Date + Time)
And onvert that in double

We can see in the example below.

```
"Date"       "Time"       "Converted Double"
"01/31/2014" "30:00.0" to "41670.3541666667"
```

Now i have done conversion as below.

"Date G " ,         "Time G ",    Concatinated_Date_Time"

"41670.0000000000","00:00.0",    "01/31/2014 00:00.0",

I used followin to convert Date G
(DT_NUMERIC,16,10)(DT_DATE)[Date G ]

But when i try to do the same with "Concatinated_Date_Time" It gives me error.
I need "Concatinated_Date_Time" in double form (41670.548400000).

Now i figured out the problem.
Problem is in "Time G" part when i try to convert "Time G" in to DT_Date it gives me error.

Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It doesn't work. it keeps giving error.
And i am surprised as well because of this behaviour.

Comment: As Concatinated_Date_Time should be of string type.
so as i did with Date G it should work for this as well
"(DT_NUMERIC,16,10)(DT_DATE)[Concatinated_Date_Time]"

But it doesn't work
And also as you suggested
"(DT_DBTIMESTAMP )Concatinated_Date_Time"
Doesn't work

Comment: No it doesn't work.

May be there is problem with formatting in Date and Time
as Date is mm/dd/yyyy and Time is hh:mm:ss.00

Comment: How "(DT_NUMERIC,16,10)(DT_DATE)(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)Concatinated_Date_Time " can work when "(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)Concatinated_Date_Time " doesn't work. Its logically not right.

Thanks for your reply

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: Error 1 [Derived Column [94]] Error: An error occurred while attempting to perform a type cast.

Error 2 [Derived Column [94]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "component "Derived Column" (94)" failed because error code 0xC0049064 occurred, and the error row disposition on "output column "Derived Column 1" (132)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Comment: So no solution yet...!

Please help me out

Comment: can you tell me why are converting datetime to double?

Comment: It is required me in a Finance company for transactions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i figured it out!

i followed folowing steps.

1. Convert string "DATE G" in to DT_DATE
2. DATEADD("Hh",0, outputfrom step 1)
3. SUBSTRING("TIME G",1,2) store in one output, SUBSTRING("TIME G",3,2) store in one output, SUBSTRING("TIME G",5,3) store in one output
4. ADD all using DATEADD() and type cast the output to DT_DATE as its output is DT_DBTIMESTAMP which can not be converted to DT_Numeric directlly.

5 Type Cast to (DT_NUMERIC) output from step 4

Thanks all

Plese let me know if its not explained well.

Thank you all